# Problemas con las rutas en Laravel 6 despues de configurar el archivo htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, rutas, laravel-6

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en laravel 6 e intentaba eliminar "/public" de la url de mi proyecto ya que las rutas de mi proyecto por defecto eran así:

```
http://me.pruebalocal.com/public/home
```

yo quiero que no tengan "/public" en la url, así:

```
http://me.pruebalocal.com/home
```

Busque en internet y varias paginas me suguieron los siguientes pasos

1: - mover el archivo .htaccess de la carpeta public a la carpeta root de mi proyecto.

2: - Cambiar el nombre del archivo server.php a index.php.

Hice los pasos pero no me cargaba ningún estilo ni los archivos js.

Seguí buscando en Internet y encontré esto:

cambiar este código en mi archivo .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Al final mi archivo .htaccess me quedo así:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Al hacer ese cambio la ruta principal  `http://me.pruebalocal.com` me carga correctamente con todo estilos y js, sin embargo no funciona ninguna otra ruta como estas `http://me.pruebalocal.com/home` o `http://me.pruebalocal.com/login`. me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]